# Efficiencies of set operations vs array operations in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

What are the differences in efficiencies between set and array for operations?

Examples:

- lookups
- iterations
- includes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Ruby, `Set` is written using an underlying `Hash` for its storage, and it should generally perform equivalent to a Hash. Thus:

- `include?`: O(1) for Set, O(n) for Array
- enumerations: O(n) for both
- `delete`: O(1) for Set, O(n) for Array

...etc.

If by "lookups" you mean looking up by index, I'd note that the default Set implementation is unordered, so it doesn't support that operation in the same way an Array does.

Comment: Can you explain why include? works O(1) in case of set? Doesn't it check each value present in set?? How Set is written using an underlying Hash?? By this mean an array like `["a", "b", "c"]` is stored like `{ "a" => "a", "b" => "b", "c" => "c" }` in Set. Am i right?