# Set vs Array , difference

Tags: ruby, arrays, set

What is the difference between `Set` and `Array` in Ruby except for the fact that sets keep unique elements while arrays can keep duplicate elements?

Comment: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100611/efficiencies-of-set-operations-vs-array-operations-in-ruby) may give you more fruitful insight on this topic.

Answer (score 42):

They are *very* different.

## [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)

- An array is an ordered list of objects.
- An array value can be accessed by referencing its integer position in the list (zero-indexed): `a[3]` references the 4th object in the array.
- There is no restriction on what the values can be—duplicate values are allowed in arrays.
- An array has an object literal notation: `[1, 'apple', String, 1, :banana]` (this creates and initializes a new Array).
- Arrays are built in to the core ruby library.

## [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)

- A set is an unordered pool of unique objects.
- Since it's unordered, there is no integer index you can use to access specific elements of a set.
- The uniqueness restriction means you can't have more than one copy of a value in the set.
- `Set` is not part of the core, but part of the standard library, and thus needs a `require 'set'`.
- Before Ruby 2.4, there was no object literal notation for sets, you had to create them via `Set.new`.

  - For Ruby >= 2.4.0 you can use [`Set[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) (e.g. `Set[1,2,3]`)

Comment: There *is* a literal notation now (as of ruby 2.4): Set[1,2,3]

Answer (score 24):

For me the main difference is that `Set`s are implemented as hashes, so you have `O(1)` membership tests for elements.

Answer (score 4):

Another important difference is in the implementation of the `include?` method: an Array compares members based on the result of the `==` method, while a Set uses the `eql?` method.

Comment: Set.new.class.superclass  #=> Object

Comment: `$ ri Set.eql?` states: "For objects of class Object, eql? is synonymous with ==."

Comment: Most sets and arrays do not contain objects of class Object. They contain objects of a subclass of Object, of which there are many for which `eql?` and `==` are not synonymous.