# When is a set better than an array?

Tags: ruby

I have used lots of time arrays in Ruby. But never get a chance to use set. My question is when Set can be useful and when it is better than an array?

Comment: BTW, this is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8338162/6419007) you're looking for. From the other answers, it might not be clear why a set would be better than an array.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, the initial definitions go as follows:

> [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html): An
>   integer-indexed collection of objects.
>
> [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html): A
>   collection of unordered values with no duplicates.

In a nutshell, you should use Set when you want to make sure that each element in the collection is unique, you want to test if a given element is present in the collection and you won't require random access to the objects.