# Does set vs array vs dictionary differ in regards to performance in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsset

I'm studying Swift from an architectural perspective as I believe Swift offers multiple tools to build a house.  I understand how arrays, dictionaries, and sets differ in regards to how values are stored however now that I've grasped this concept I'd like to know if they differ in regards to performance?  Maybe there are things I haven't thought of but right now I'm thinking I'd choose one of these Swift tools based on how I'd like the information to be regurgitated further down the road in the program.  So if there is anything additional I should know about or consider when picking one of these tools, please feel free to comment and I'll research the concepts further.

Thanks in advance.

-a noob

Comment: Depends on what you're using it for.

Comment: Thanks @dan is this a wide net of use cases?

Comment: Yes. They are completely different data structures that are (abstractly) language unspecific. I would recommend understanding what each one does under the hood and that should point you to when they should be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338133/set-vs-array-difference#8338237 http://www.ufthelp.com/2013/04/dictionary-vs-array.html

Comment: Going to share this [Big-O](http://bigocheatsheet.com)

Comment: There's a worth to read article about performance of each data types.

[READ IT](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123100/collection-data-structures-swift-2)